# Securing a computer using two routers

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have 2 routers: one with wi-fi (router_A) and another without wi-fi (router_B). I want to keep my work computer as much isolated from wi-fi as possible for security purposes. What would be the most secure configuration?

For example:
option 1: Connect router_B to cable modem. Connect work computer to router_B. Connect router_A to router_B.

option 2: Connect router_A to cable modem. Connect router_B to router_A. Connect work computer to router_B.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly the second option (although if you don't connect your computer to router A both are acceptable) but computer safety is a looong topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the 2 configurations, option 2 is marginally more secure - but there is not much in it, and it can (possibly not noticeably depending on what you are doing) decrease the quality of your work computer by adding an adding an additional hop and slightly boosting the priority of traffic from the WIFI router.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that the configuration 2 would isolate the work computer from wi-fi. I checked that with a program WNetWatcher. It seems that a computer connected to router_A doesn't "see" the work computer. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: If I understand your definition of "isolate" correctly yes.

Comment: If a hacker breaks into the wi-fi network, he will not have access to the work computer. That's what I mean by "isolate". Could you please explain why option 2 is better in this respect?

Comment: Option 2 is better because (from the perspective of Router B / your office PC) it puts the WIFI router on the WAN/untrusted side of the connection, rather then on the LAN (trusted side of the connection).  Thus if Router A is compromised it does not compromise the integrity of Router B.   In the "opposite" scenario if router A is compromised the attacker can probably (making assumptions on your setup) get access to the office computer without actually going through the "routing process" on Router B as the WAN interface on router A will be on the same network as the LAN interface on router B.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Do you think it would be better to use some other device (bridge, switch, etc.) instead of Router B?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, but in the general usage case, no.  (General usage case - No local servers that you want to reach externally, simple setup with reasonable security).  Certainly bridges and switches in place of routers would create rather then solve security problems - but depending on the Internet connection you could "do it better" by having the Internet connection coming into a device (eg an ADSL router) and then plugging both router A and router B into that device, thus both isolating the office from the home network and vice versa and neater routing/logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think in option 1 your work computer will have better access to internet but as work computer and router A both are connected to router B and router B working as wifi then your work computer is exposed to wifi more compared to option 2

where in option 2 you are adding 1 more router in between wifi( If configured on router A) and work computer but reducing performance( decrease in internet speed at work computer).

Comment: _"..and router B working as wifi.."_  Sorry, but router B has no wi-fi.